# Protobuf c# to java deserializing multiple messages

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am trying to parse multiple protocol buffer messages in java which are generated in vb.net

I am using the excellent protobuf-net to stream multiple messages to java as per below:

```
ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(Of Msg)(postStream, msg, 
       ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Base128)
```

In Java, I am using following code to parse the messages

```
final byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
for (int c = ins.read(buffer); c >= 0; c = ins.read(buffer)) {
  Msg msg = Msg.parseDelimitedFrom(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
}
```

Problem is after first message is parsed, it throws error for parsing second time with following error:

> com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either than the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.

Should the buffer size and message size be same?  If yes, then how should I parse it, especially for large messages.

Comment: Removing `[C#]` and `[vb.net]` as the answer doesn't appear to need to refer to either of these.

Comment: Hi, I have a very similar problem could you elaborate further on your solution. I have C# file that parses a file containing many proto messages

and it uses the same code you pasted

ProtoBuf.Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(Of Msg)(postStream, msg, 
       ProtoBuf.PrefixStyle.Base128)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to read directly from the original stream, not a block at a time. (Even if you know every message is exactly 4096 bytes, you cannot be sure to read that much at once)  I suggest you use

```
while(stream still open) {
    Msg msg = Msg.parseDelimitedFrom(ins);
}
```

Note: TCP is a streaming protocol, not  a message protocol.  You are only guaranteed to read one byte at a time, and any extra bytes you get is a bonus.

Comment: Problem is if I am sending n messages in a httpwebrequest stream, how do I loop inputstream in java to get n messages.

Comment: @gaurav46 Put it in a loop?

Comment: @PeterLawery Hmm...I should have thought that :).  thanks. Let me try it out.

Comment: @gaurav46 The tricky bit is knowing when to stop the loop.  Usually there is some hint in the protocol (or you expect the connection to be closed)

Comment: @PeterLawery  You are right.  Its tricky.  I was able to parse multiple messages with following code changed in java as per your suggerstion.  while (true){
    Msg msg = Msg.parseDelimitedFrom(new ByteArrayInputStream(ins));
    if msg == null)
 break; 
}

Comment: You might be able to change this to a "do / while" loop. ;)